# listAdapter in SherlockListFragment

Tags: android, android-listview, actionbarsherlock

I want to set up a ListView, but want the activity to be among Sherlock tabs.

here is my code

```
public class PlayListActivity extends SherlockListFragment{
    // Songs list
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    @Override
    public SherlockFragmentActivity getSherlockActivity() {
        return super.getSherlockActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Get the view from fragmenttab3.xml
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.playlist, container, false);
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsListData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        SongsManager plm = new SongsManager();
        // get all songs from sdcard
        this.songsList = plm.getPlayList();

        // looping through playlist
        for (int i = 0; i < songsList.size(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> song = songsList.get(i);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsListData.add(song);
        }

        // Adding menuItems to ListView

        ListAdapter Ladapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, songsListData,
                R.layout.playlist_item, new String[] { "songTitle" }, new int[] {
                        R.id.songTitle });
```

I get errors just above here when declaring ListAdapter , it says SimpleAdapter is undefined.
it worked fine when the class extended ListActivity but since I want tabs and swipe I extended sherlockListActivity and I guess the class isn't available in Sherlock
Any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not usign fragments then extend your activity from `SherlockListActivity` else 
Extend your activity class from `SherlockFragmentActivity` and add  `SherlockListFragment` fragment.

Comment: I am using fragments 
I want one of my fragment above to be a list view 
please explain more, how can I add SherlockListFragment